# orange dot instead of green dot

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios-provisioning

I am newbie for iPhone app and wanted to run the xcode 4.5 project to iPhone (6.1 ios version).

I am following [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPwlhKgZHCM) for the same.

However in organiser, next to my iPhone, I see orange/ yellow dot instead of green dot.

What things do I need to do to make it to green as video says it should be green

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating to Xcode 4.6 which comes with the iOS SDK 6.1?

Comment: Does it say something like 'Use this device for development' on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your xcode to 4.6 and you'll have green dot again.

Comment: one quick question... can i open 4.5 project in 4.6? i heard i have to do some setting to run 4.5 project to 4.6...

Comment: No nothing special as I have recently updated but didn't did any thing special. So just download and have fun. :)